# Servotimer2.h is not recognised as a library by arduino uno

Tags: servo, library

I'm doing a project for school with an arduino uno. I want to control a motor using a RF-module as remote control. I need the library Virtualwire.h to use the RF-module and the library Servo.h to control the motor. I downloaded the library Servotimer2.h because Virtualwire.h and Servo.h both want to use timer 1 of the arduino. I added this library to arduino libraries but arduino doesn't recognise it as a library when I include it to my program.
can someone help me with this issue? I tried to find a solution but can't find it. 
Many thanks allready!

Comment: Could you explain exactly how and where you added the `Servertimer2.h` library? Also, how are you including it in your source code?

Comment: Thanks allready for your first reaction.
This is the proces I followed : I downloaded the library Servotimer2.h as a Zip file. Then I added this zip file by clicking -> include library -> add ZIP library... an then selected the zip file servotimer2.

Comment: Afterwards I included the library to my program. And allready from hereone I remark that the library is not accepted like other libraries. Arduino doesn't seem to recognize it as a library because the name of the library stays black. 
When I compile this, I get this error messages:
error: conflicting declaration 'typedef bool boolean'
 typedef bool boolean;
error: 'boolean' has a previous declaration as 'typedef uint8_t boolean'
 typedef uint8_t boolean;
I am just starting to use arduino and error could be obvious, but I don't get it yet.
Thanks for your help.